# What is causing this RichApi error when trying to use insertInlinePictureFromBase64()

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I am trying to replace the token in the word document with the image i have in base64. But i get an unhelpful error
[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4hgj.png)

Here is the function thats not working

```
async function insertImage(token, image) {
  console.log("adding image");

  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const results = context.document.body.search(token);
    await context.sync();
    results.load();
    await context.sync();
    console.log(results.items);

    for (let i = 0; i < results.items.length; i++) {
      const pasteMeHere = results.items[i];
      pasteMeHere.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(image, "Replace");
      pasteMeHere.delete();
      
    }
    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

I have tried different images, one of which from the ms script lab repo which i confirmed working. I have also tried different locations including using the `paragraphs.getLast()` function.

Comment: Before you do anything else, rewrite the function so that you are not calling `context.sync` in a loop. This can cause problems with timing and other issues. See https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern

Comment: Thanks for that, im new to using OfficeJs, i made the change and everything works the same so thats good. It didn't fix the problem though of course.

Comment: Please update your question to show the new code.

Comment: Sorry, new to asking questions on here wasn't aware of the etiquette to update the original post.

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) does it work if you replace the `image` parameter with some text in the call of `insertInlinePictureFromBase64`? Is the token replace with the text or do you get the error? (2) Can you reproduce the error in Script Lab?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in updating you, the issue was the image I was using had a string at the beginning. I found the answer by following your suggestions. I did try different images including the one in script lab prior to posting but i must have missed something when copying it. Thanks for your help!